# cygwin doesn't execute make

Tags: makefile, cygwin, mingw

I am very new to cygwin and recently installed it because I need to compile some fortran files. I installed all libraries (and its dependencies) I need, but when I execute `make` to run the makefile, nothing is happening:

```
user@PC1 ~
$ make

user@PC1 ~
$
```

No error, no nothing. When I directly execute the file contained in the makefile: same result. All files required are contained in my folder where I run make. However, the package seems to be installed just fine when I call `where make` or `which make`. I reinstalled everything multiple times, but still nothing is happening. I then tried to [bind the MinGW make](https://cs.nyu.edu/rgrimm/teaching/fa05-oop/windows-make.html) so I can use it in cygwin and by calling this version of make, I receive the error I'd expect:

```
user@PC1 ~
$ mymake
C:\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Unfortunately, I need the make-package from cygwin itself to work, but I have no idea what's going on. Any hints? Calling make.exe doesn't work either.

**Update**: I just installed cygwin and all required packages on my laptop and there everything works as intended...no problems in runing make.

Comment: which version of make package you have ( `cygcheck -c make`) and what it the output of `cygcheck make` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and managed to fix this following those steps:

- Open the cygwin setup and completely uninstall make (reinstalling failed for me). If you haven't deleted the download folder yet, you can select "Install from Local Directory" to make things faster.
- Once uninstalled, re-run the setup again and check `make`, install the dependencies if needed.

Tested with make version 4.2.1-1 on my system, and got it working again.

Comment: Yeah... there probably is some underlying explanation here xD Glad it worked out!